# How to pass login data to the next state in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am working in Angular 4. Here I have created a login state and I need to pass the login information the next state on changing state in success block. In Angularjs, by using `stateParams` we can implement this one. But I don't know how to do it in Angular 4. How can I implement this one in Angular 4?

Below is my code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import {
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    Validators,
    FormBuilder,
    AbstractControl, 
    ValidatorFn,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) { }
signup(){
    this.router.navigate(['register']);
}

 createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('ck_543700d9f8c08268d75d3efefb302df4fad70a8f:cs_f1514261bbe154d662eb5053880d40518367c901')); 
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  }   
onSubmit(userForm:NgForm){
    console.log(userForm.value);
    let headers=new Headers();
     this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
const body={
"username": userForm.value.email,
  "password": userForm.value.password
}
    console.log(body);
    console.log(headers);
this.http.post('https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',body,{
        headers:headers
        })
      .subscribe(
      data => {
              console.log(data);
           this.router.navigate(['home']);
            },
            err => {
              console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
            }
      );

}   

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb1 animated wow slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">Login Page</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //breadcrumbs -->
    <!-- login -->
    <div class="login">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="animated wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay=".5s">Login Form</h3>
            <p class="est animated wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay=".5s">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <div class="login-form-grids animated wow slideInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required=" " name="email" ngModel>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required=" " name="password" ngModel>
                    <div class="forgot">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
            </div>
            <h4 class="animated wow slideInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s">For New People</h4>
            <p class="animated wow slideInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s"><a (click)="signup()">Register Here</a> (Or) go back to <a routerLink="/home">Home<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your current component

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], {queryParams: {data: data}});
```

And you could subscribe in target component :

```
constructor(private _route:ActivatedRoute){}

this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
});
```

Comment: Iam getting data as {"queryParams":"[object Object]"}.Nothing was displaying eventhough stringifying it.

Comment: @srujana -- make sure the square brackets are only around the url string in the first parameter of the `navigate` function. Putting the `queryParams` (which should be the second parameter of `navigate`) inside those square brackets is one way to create your error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in `router.navigate`:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], { queryParams: { param: 'value' } });
```

Or simply:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], param);
```

And you can get them in another component as `observable`, like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
/* other imports */

@Component({
  /* selector, template and so on */
})

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'ActivatedRoute'.error is occurring

Comment: @srujana, sure, you should import `ActivatedRoute`. I have updated the answer.